# How to Add Columns in one Table from another table which are not exists in Table (Alter Table)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I Have 2 tables

```
1.details
2.detailhistory
```

Columns

```
1.details
 - id
 - Name
 - Data

2.detailhistory
 - id
 - Name
```

I want to Alter Table (detailhistory) with add new columns which are exists in details table not not avialable in detailshistory

I Need Output As (Updated Columns in detailshistory)

```
2.detailhistory
 - id
 - Name
 - Data
```

I Tried to Get Columns which are not exists in detailshistory table

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='details' and 
COLUMN_NAME not in (select COLUMN_NAME  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='detailshistory')
```

Comment: what is the error in your query

Comment: it show columns but how i can alter the table using this result

Comment: you need to use `ALTER TABLE` command

Comment: @squirrel i know that but how can i alter a table with dynamic data

Comment: Don't do it.  Use `join` when you need those columns.